# Occupied k values in band structure

Tags: electronic-band-theory

In solid state physics you can calculate the band structure of a material, which is effectively the dispersion E_n(k), which depends on the wavevector as well as the band index. What I don't understand is this: Which states are occupied in a band? With this I mean: Which k values correspond to states actually occupied by electrons. Since k is continous it cannot be all k values since there is not an infinite number of electrons. For a plane wave dispersion I remember that you can use periodic boundary conditions to get a quantization of k in states that are actually occupied. How do you do this for a general dispersion, i.e. a general band structure?

Comment: Band structure is for ideal periodic infinite solid and it has infinite number of electrons. The states are just occupied as $f(E-E_f)$, where f is the fermi dirac duatribution, E is the state energy and $E_f$ ja the Fermi-energy. In general, the states below Fermi-energy are occupied.

Comment: Okay so what about the finite case. Is there not quantization condition on k? I remember that for an ideal infinite solid with plane wave dispersion you can get a quantization condition on k, so I don't understand that this shouldnt be possible for the general case.

Comment: Technically the number of $k$ points in the Brillouin zone equals the number of unit cells in the crystal. So it's only for the idealised, infinitely large crystal that the $k$ points are continuous.

Comment: You might still be concerned that there are a countable number of electrons, but a continuum of k. This is where you use regularity of the dependence on k.